# How to make ajax false for only one menuitem in primefaces.

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

How to make ajax false for only one menuitem in primefaces.

I am using c:foreach for iterating menuitem list.

C:if inside c:foreach will work ? 
Here is the code snippet below.

```
<p:menuButton  id="Button" value="Select" >
                        <c:forEach var="itemListVar" items="#{itemList}">
                            <p:menuitem id="#{itemListVar}"  value="#{itemListVar}" actionListener="#{bean.processSelect}" process="@this" ajax="false"
                                 update="table:messages" rendered="true">
                                <f:attribute name="selectedRow" value="#{itemVar}" />
                                <f:attribute name="selectedAction" value="#{itemListVar}" />
                             </p:menuitem> 
                        </c:forEach>
</p:menuButton>
```

Comment: How would you do that when not using a foreach but a statically build menu?

Comment: You could define a property in the POJO and refer it from your xhtml like all the others -  `ajax="#{itemListVar.ajax}"`

Comment: I will try the solution and provide an update..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ajax="#{itemListVar.ajax}"
```

This worked. Thanks